# Export layers in QGIS to one shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I have a group of shapefiles already loaded into QGIS.
How do I export them to a .shp, .dpf, and .shx file that I can put into a folder and load onto another instance of QGIS?
[image: QGIS Setup]

Comment: The shapefile format has a 4MB size limit. Those layers look extremely detailed (lots of detail = large file size). Have a look at the original file sizes to see if they will all fit into a single shapefile. If not, you may want to look into other formats (such as geopackage).

Comment: @csk shapefile have a 2GB size limit not 4MB but the advise to use geopackage is still a good one for lots of reasons (to read more on SHP vs geopackage : http://switchfromshapefile.org/)

Comment: Oops.Thanks for the correction @J.R.

Comment: @csk The total file size is 1.65 GB. Is there a way that I could programatically merge them using python?

Comment: That's a different question, but have a look around before you post a new question. I suspect it's already been answered.

Comment: You have the answer here:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/300630/how-to-use-merge-vector-layers-in-qgis-using-geopackages-as-output-with-fids-d

Your solution is to build a Geopackage file by merging all your layers using OGR2OGR.

Geopackage files can even store the styles if you want to add them.